# How to read image from Firebase using OpencCV?

Tags: python, firebase, opencv, pyrebase

Is there any idea for reading image from Firebase using OpenCV? Or do I have to download the pictures first and then do the cv.imread function from the local folder ?

Is there any way that I could just use `cv.imread(link_of_picture_from_firebase)`?

Comment: How did you upload the image into Firebase in the first place? You don't need to save the image to disk - you should be able to fetch the image from Firebase and then use `cv.imdecode()` to convert the JPEG-encoded data into a Numpy array.

Comment: hmmm can you help me for the cv.imdecode() please ? What is the argument of imdecode ? Do you have any reference ? Thank you !

Comment: I uploaded the photo using pyrebase library , it is db.child("....").put(data)

Comment: Have a look here https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html

Comment: What is *"data"* in your last comment above please? It must be some type of JSON serialisable data, so how did you get initialise this variable?

Comment: it is a variable , so lets say

data = {"data" : "value"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you can:

- read a JPEG from disk,
- convert to JSON,
- upload to Firebase

Then you can:

- retrieve the image back from Firebase
- decode the JPEG data back into a Numpy array
- save the retrieved image on disk

---

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import numpy as np
import cv2
from base64 import b64encode, b64decode
import pyrebase

config = {
   "apiKey": "SECRET",
   "authDomain": "SECRET",
   "databaseURL": "SECRET",
   "storageBucket": "SECRET",
   "appId": "SECRET",
   "serviceAccount": "FirebaseCredentials.json"
}

# Initialise and connect to Firebase
firebase = pyrebase.initialize_app(config)
db = firebase.database()

# Read JPEG image from disk...
# ... convert to UTF and JSON
# ... and upload to Firebase
with open("image2.jpg", 'rb') as f:
    data = f.read()
str = b64encode(data).decode('UTF-8')
db.child("image").set({"data": str})


# Retrieve image from Firebase
retrieved = db.child("image").get().val()
retrData = retrieved["data"]
JPEG = b64decode(retrData)

image = cv2.imdecode(np.frombuffer(JPEG,dtype=np.uint8), cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
cv2.imwrite('result.jpg',image)
```

Comment: okayy I will give a try first , but for the picture , is it possible for me to retrieve it from the firebase storage ? Because I uploaded it with my android app , which is pure JPEG image