# How do I upload a file to firebase using raspberypi 3b+

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, raspberry-pi, pyrebase

I am a beginer with raspberrypi and I am currently working on it and want to upload files to firebase.
I have tried using pyrebase to upload data to firebase .
The code I have used is

```
import pyrebase
config = {
"apiKey": "AIzaSyDQIr6KCJTROzrAs8x9YvSSFo5zZ06N",
"authDomain": "achyuth13451601.firebaseapp.com",
"databaseURL": "https://achyuth13451601.firebaseio.com",
"storageBucket": "achyuth13451601.appspot.com",
}
firebase = pyrebase.initialize_app(config)
auth = firebase.auth()
user = auth.sign_in_with_email_and_password(email, password)
db = firebase.database()
data = {
    "name": "Mortimer 'Morty' Smith"
}
results = db.child("users").push(data, user['idToken'])
```

but I am getting an error that unauthorized for url and permission denied

Comment: If the kind of files are images, think about to use Cloudinary service rather than uploding images to the database.

Comment: This is related https://stackoverflow.com/a/59346488/2836621

Answer (score 0):

Firebase uses **firebase security rules** to check if you are allowed to have **access** to any data or files. Firebase rules exist for both the **databases** (realtime, cloud) and firebase **storage** which you are using. By default firebase storage security rules don't allow to upload files. You must go to your [firebase storage console](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/start?hl=el) and check them and change them to fit your needs.