# convert string image to a real image in python

Tags: python, opencv, base64

i'm trying to get an image from a string message sended by a socket, so the message before sending it, it has been decoded in base64. Now in my python server i am using this instruction to convert the string image to a real image in order to give it like an argument in cv2.imwrite() and cv2.imshow()

```py
image = np.fromstring(string_image, np.uint8)
cv2.imwrite("image.png", image)
cv2.imshow("image", image)
```

the code like that gives me an image but not the same as it supposed to be, i mean by that is like i got a gray image with orizontal edges only and nothing else.
and if i add the follow instruction between the np.fromstring and cv2.imwrite :

```py
image = cv2.imdecode(image, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
```

i got the empty image error. What should i add or change in my code to get the real image ?

Comment: Look at last 4 lines here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/59346488/2836621

Comment: Please share the first 30-40 characters from `string_image`.

Comment: @MarkSetchell always the same problm, with the solution in that link i got an empty image

Comment: @MarkSetchell here is the first 40 characters : gZN+/4CSff9+jof/f4+I/4SWlP+Fl5X/gY+Y/3qI

Comment: That doesn't look like a base64-encoded PNG. It should start with `iVBORw0KGgo=` See https://stackoverflow.com/a/49690539/2836621 What did you actually send?

Comment: @MarkSetchell actually i'm sending that image from unity with c# script via a socket in my c# code i used that instruction to transform the image :
```c#
Byte[] pixels = image.Pixels; 
string string_image = Convert.ToBase64String(pixels);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are too many things going wrong here. First you need to decide **what** you are going to send. Then you need to decide **how** you are going to send it.

As regards **what** you are going to send - you could send:

- a JPEG - this has the advantage that it will be small and transmit fastest whilst taking least network bandwidth. It is also self-contained - the recipient can work out the width and height from the JPEG header. *Disadvantages*: potentially has less quality.
- a PNG - much the same as JPEG but a bit bigger and better quality.
- raw pixels - which seems to be what you are currently doing maybe? This will take the most network bandwidth and be the slowest. Also, the receiver will not know the width, the height, the bits per pixel or if there is any sub-sampling, so you will have to transmit this with the pixels.

If you send as JPEG or PNG, you will be able to just use Python `write()` to write the data to disk as a JPEG or PNG at the receiving end. If you want to process the image at the receiving end, you will want to convert it to a Numpy array with `cv2.imdecode()`.

If you send as raw pixels, you will not use `cv2.imdecode()` at the receiving end because you will have raw pixels, so you will need to put them into a Numpy array and reshape according to the height and width that you remembered to transmit along with the pixels like I said above.

Then there is the question of **how** you send it. You seem to be base64-encoding but I wonder why as that just makes the image 33% bigger for no reason.